# Open div when click a another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have a html structure. With the following:

```
<div class="edit"><a class="formtri" href="#">CHANGE</a>
```

And:

```
  <div id="user_adr" style="display:none">
```

I want, when i click CHANGE, get `user_adr` div on front. Ajax or other solution. I tried jQuery `.load` function but it's not work. How can i do this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A3uMP/)

Comment: How do you "open" a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternatively you can use toggle functionality.

```
$('.edit').on('click',function(){
   $('#user_adr').toggle();
});
```

if not toggle.  then alternative method of toggle is this.

```
$('.edit').on('click',function(){
if('#user_adr').is('visible'))
    {
         $('#user_adr').show();
    }
    else
    {
         $('#user_adr').hide();
    }
});
```

//to change display to none

```
$('#yourDivId).attr('display','none');
```

Comment: Ok but when get user_adr div, i want to display:none change divs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to show / hide html element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DXMg2/)**

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
   $('#user_adr').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `jquery ui. dialog()` method to show a dialog box.  like this.  [Jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if in case there is any other div with same class name edit above solutions may not be helpful so better u keep a unique id as "change"

```
<div class="edit"><a class="formtri" id="change" href="#">CHANGE</a>

$("#change").on("click", function(){
$('#user_adr').show();
});    

$("#change").on("click", function(){
$('#user_adr').toggle();
});
```